# Inserting custom data to the_post() during loop

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts, get-posts

I have some posts on my WordPress site, and let's say I want to add a random number for each post with `$num` as key and `random()` as value. Then I want to access them with something like:

`$post->num` or `post_num()`

Can this be done during The Loop? Since the value will change every time it is executed, I need to make it during The Loop. I can't add this random number as a custom field.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's not very common, but perfectly viable and nifty technique.

After the posts are retrieved in `WP_Query` they are passed through `the_posts` filter like this (where `$this` is `WP_Query` instance):

```
$this->posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'the_posts', array( $this->posts, &$this ) );
```

You just loop through array and assign the extra data you need to objects. Don't forget to check the query for being *right* query you want to target.